# Highlight an array item that was not found in the database

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm writing a program that fetches data from a SQL database using php and jquery by providing multiple serial numbers. each serial number is in an individual input (all together as array), than i process data with jquery ajax and pass it to the php file. i cant figure out how to highlight or add a red border to the input with the not founded serial number. I can do it if there is only one input in the array but not if there are more. Is any way to do this?

What ive tired so far

collecting the serials with :

> var serial = $("input[name='getID[]']");
>
> var arrayserial = serial.map(function(){return
>   "'"+$(this).val()+"'";}).get();

Sending the serials to the php with:

> > $.ajax({
> >                               type: "POST",
> >                               url: "proccess.php",
> >                               data: 'serial='+ arrayserial,
> >                               success: function(data) {
> >                                   $('.results').html(data);
>
> ```
>                       }
>                   });
> ```

On the php file

> $serial = $_POST['serial']; sqlsrv_query($ConnReq,"SELECT * FROM
>   TestData INNER JOIN Acceptances ON TestData.Applicant =
>   Acceptances.Acceptance_ID WHERE MN IN ($serial)");

than i fetch the rows with

> sqlsrv_fetch_array

ive wrapped the code with

> if ($row_count != 0){} <== (a var to count rows)

and

> else{ echo "Nothing found
>
> ";} <== (this works if there is only one input)

Comment: Can you post some code of what you tried so far?

Comment: wrote what ive tried above

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the highlighting either creating a class with the new css or directly altering the css via jquery should do the trick. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/22jMc/3/) with highlighting all even serials

To apply it to a certain element. for example, if you want to highlight only the 4th box, you can change:

```
$('#someForm input:nth-child(even)').
```

To:

```
$('#someForm input:nth-child(5)').
```

But I get the feeling this is not your only problem, yes?

EDIT: The solution to your other problem:

You can create a temporary table which holds the serials you wanted to test and compare them to the ones you have in your database.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS serials (ID VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO serials(ID) VALUES('1st Serial'),('2nd Serial'),('3rd Serial'),...,('n-th Serial');
SELECT * FROM serials WHERE serials.ID NOT IN (SELECT nameOfColumnWithSerials FROM YourTableWithSerials)
```

Executing the 3 queries will result in the third one giving you a list of all the serials that do not exist in your database and after you close the connection to the database the temporary table will disappear.

How about that?

Comment: thnx for your reply but my prob is: i send the req to fetch the serials from the database but if one of the serials is not found, the input with this serials value should be highlighted

Comment: so you send a request, does this request, with a few serials, and the server tells you which of those serials are found in the database and which are not?

Comment: basically yes, the server sends back the serials that were found but ignores the not found serial, i want to notify the user that this one is not found

Comment: temporary table... ill use that as the last option because i dont want to edit the database just read it, but could there be an easier way like comparing the fetched serials (they get posted back via jquery with some other rows) with the ones in the inputs

Comment: the temporary table is deleted automatically when the connection is closed. Thus it's never actually created inside the data base

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49256/discussion-between-hristo-valkanov-and-erind-dollaku)